# Bootstrap 3: Display panels inside their wells on browser resize

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, panel

How can I get these panels to stay inside their wells when the browser window is resized (particularly to the width of a mobile device)? It'd probably be best to resize the well too. I have some overlapping issues as well.

Here's full width:
[image: Here's full width]

Here's mobile width (ish):
[image: Here's mobile width]

I'd like that Summary to be in the Volume & Fees well, on its own line, not overlapping with the other wells.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="container"> 
<div class="row clearfix" id="content-row">     
    <div class="col-md-12 column">
        <div class="well" id="volume-fees-well">
            <div class="row clearfix" id="volume-fees-row">                                                
                <div class="col-md-9 column" id="volume-fees-chart">
                    <div class="panel panel-primary" id="volume-fees-panel">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3 class="panel-title">
                                Volume &amp; Fees
                            </h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <svg></svg>
                        </div>                      
                    </div>                                      
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 column">
                    <div class="panel panel-primary" id="volume-fees-summary-panel">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3 class="panel-title">
                                Summary
                            </h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="well" id="vehicle-class-well">
```

I'm using D3 for the charts, which is what the svg is for.

I'm using the Bootswatch Yeti theme and the standard Bootstrap.css. The only CSS I've overridden from the Bootstrap.css is:

```
#content-row {
margin-top: 50px;
}

#volume-fees-row, #vehicle-class-row, #consignor-map-row, #buyer-map-row {
    height: 450px;
}

.panel {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.panel-body {
    height: 400px;
}
```

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Have you tried using the `col-xs-*` class?

Comment: Not yet - I'll give that a shot. Shouldn't have overlooked that in the first place. I designed the layout on [LayoutIt](http://www.layoutit.com/) which only gave me the classes for md size. Thanks, Adrift! I'll report back!

Comment: Worked like a charm! Added the col-xs-12 class to the wells and each panel within the wells. Thank you!

Edit: @Adrift - If you want to make a post with the answer I'll happily give you credit!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I get these panels to stay inside their wells when the browser window is resized

Just use the [`.col-xs-*`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries) class (instead of `col-md-*`):

```
<div class="container"> 
<div class="row clearfix" id="content-row">     
    <div class="col-xs-12 column">
    <div class="well" id="volume-fees-well">
        <div class="row clearfix" id="volume-fees-row">                                                
            <div class="col-xs-9 column" id="volume-fees-chart">
                <div class="panel panel-primary" id="volume-fees-panel">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">
                            Volume &amp; Fees
                        </h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <svg></svg>
                    </div>                      
                </div>                                      
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 column">
                <div class="panel panel-primary" id="volume-fees-summary-panel">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">
                            Summary
                        </h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="well" id="vehicle-class-well">
```